# How to put parameters in query.script.script.params?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query just like this:

```
{
 "script": {
     "script": {
     "lang": "painless",
     "params": {
         "maxPrice": 1000000,
         "minPrice": 50,
         "now": "{{now}}"
                },
     "source": "(doc['selling_price'].value == 0 && doc['normal_price'].value >= params.minPrice && doc['normal_price'].value <= params.maxPrice) || (doc['selling_price'].value > 0 && doc['selling_price'].value >= params.minPrice && doc['selling_price'].value <= params.maxPrice && params.now <= doc['selling_price_end_time'].value.getMillis() && params.now >= doc['selling_price_start_time'].value.getMillis())"
                 }
            }
}
```

When I trying to put `minPrice` and `maxPrice` into parameters in a template just like `now` like this :

```
"params": {
     "maxPrice": "{{maxPrice}}",
     "minPrice": "{{minPrice}}",
     "now": "{{now}}"
          },
```

Then when I run :

```
{
    "id": "my_template",
    "params": {
        "query_all": "My goi",
        "maxPrice": 100000000,
        "minPrice": 50,
        "now": 1421427600000,
```

I received this:

```
"failures": [
    {
        "shard": 4,
        "index": "dev_index_sku_list",
        "node": "jSpDqKHwSMeWsUxxoD9-5w",
        "reason": {
            "type": "script_exception",
            "reason": "runtime error",
            "script_stack": [
                "(doc['selling_price'].value == 0 && doc['normal_price'].value >= params.minPrice && doc['normal_price'].value <= params.maxPrice) || (doc['selling_price'].value > 0 && doc['selling_price'].value >= params.minPrice && doc['selling_price'].value <= params.maxPrice &&
```

Ridiculously, when I set up `now` as a parameter it works, but not for the case for `minPrice` and `maxPrice`:

---

The logic behind the `source` is:

Our data have:

```
NormalPrice: 200                          #this is the normal price
SellingPrice:  100                        #this is actually the promotion price
selling_price_start_time:  "2020-01-01"   #duration of promotion price
selling_price_end_time:    "2020-01-30"
```

The logic:

if `selling_price` != 0 and `now` in the promotion time then filter within `minPrice` and `maxPrice`
else then filter by `normalPrice` within `minPrice` and `maxPrice`

---

Currently working on version 7 of elasticSearch

Comment: You cannot use Mustache templated values in the `params` section of a painless script, that doesn't make any sense. With `{{now}}` it's probably a coincidence that it works, but `now` doesn't have the value you expect. What values do you expect `{{minPrice}}`, `{{maxPrice}}` and `{{now}}` to have?

Comment: it actually works, and I just found out. The solution is to pass `Long.parseLong` to convert string from parameters. Just like this `Long.parseLong(params.min_price)`. Anyway thanks for your contribution